# iOS - how to fix broken constraints of AutoLayout?

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

I am using AutoLayout to configure views of my iOS app.

Everything went smoothly, but I got some problems recently.

A plethora of dirty warning alerts were printed on the log screen and the app was became very slowly.

But compiling complete successfully and the screen was configured as I wanted it to be.

*The below log is a part of "A plethora of dirty warning alerts" but isn't related my core question. So It's okay to ignore this.*

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170280f00 UIView:0x10296ee30.width == UIView:0x102971940.width   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170281040 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x102971940]   (active, names: '|':Common.TopFilterView:0x102b2d9b0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170281090 H:[UIView:0x102971940]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':Common.TopFilterView:0x102b2d9b0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170281310 Common.TopFilterView:0x102b2d9b0.trailing == UIView:0x102971ae0.trailing - 8   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170281360 H:|-(8)-[Common.TopFilterView:0x102b2d9b0]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x102971ae0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170280ff0 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x102971ae0]   (active, names: '|':dealer.CarAuctionHeaderView:0x10296ded0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1702810e0 H:[UIView:0x102971ae0]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':dealer.CarAuctionHeaderView:0x10296ded0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170282e40 '_UITemporaryLayoutWidth' dealer.CarAuctionHeaderView:0x10296ded0.width == 0   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170280f00 UIView:0x10296ee30.width == UIView:0x102971940.width   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2017-10-11 11:52:35.171573 dealer[633:151926] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170281310 Common.TopFilterView:0x102b2d9b0.trailing == UIView:0x102971ae0.trailing - 8   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170281360 H:|-(8)-[Common.TopFilterView:0x102b2d9b0]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x102971ae0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170280ff0 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x102971ae0]   (active, names: '|':dealer.CarAuctionHeaderView:0x10296ded0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1702810e0 H:[UIView:0x102971ae0]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':dealer.CarAuctionHeaderView:0x10296ded0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170282e40 '_UITemporaryLayoutWidth' dealer.CarAuctionHeaderView:0x10296ded0.width == 0   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170281310 Common.TopFilterView:0x102b2d9b0.trailing == UIView:0x102971ae0.trailing - 8   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2017-10-11 11:52:35.172660 dealer[633:151926] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174098970 Common.TopFilterView:0x102b2d9b0.height == 24   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17009fe50 Common.AuctionBoardView:0x10296e650.height == 32   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170281270 V:|-(0)-[Common.AuctionBoardView:0x10296e650]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x102971ae0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1702811d0 Common.TopFilterView:0x102b2d9b0.bottom == UIView:0x102971ae0.bottom - 8   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1702813b0 V:[Common.AuctionBoardView:0x10296e650]-(18)-[Common.TopFilterView:0x102b2d9b0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170281540 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x102971ae0]   (active, names: '|':dealer.CarAuctionHeaderView:0x10296ded0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170281590 V:[UIView:0x102971ae0]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':dealer.CarAuctionHeaderView:0x10296ded0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170283fc0 '_UITemporaryLayoutHeight' dealer.CarAuctionHeaderView:0x10296ded0.height == 0   (active)>"
)
```

Not all of these were errors I could understand, but I solved these to various methods.

However, A type of error still exists that I really can't understand.

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170490900 V:|-(0)-[Common.RippleView:0x10a2d3600]   (active, names: '|':Common.DetailProgressView:0x10a2f2ac0'\Uc131\Ub2a5\Uc810\Uac80\Uae30\Ub85d\Ubd80' )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17068d890 V:[Common.RippleView:0x10a2d3600]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':Common.DetailProgressView:0x10a2f2ac0'\Uc131\Ub2a5\Uc810\Uac80\Uae30\Ub85d\Ubd80' )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170681ae0 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x10b745ee0.top == Common.DetailProgressView:0x10b7460a0'\Uac80\Ucc28\Uacb0\Uacfc'.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170681b80 'UISV-canvas-connection' V:[Common.DetailProgressView:0x10a2d9840'\Uc774\Uc804\Ub4f1\Ub85d\Uc99d']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x10b745ee0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170681ea0 'UISV-hiding' UIStackView:0x10b745ee0.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170681c20 'UISV-spacing' V:[Common.DetailProgressView:0x10b7460a0'\Uac80\Ucc28\Uacb0\Uacfc']-(8)-[Common.DetailProgressView:0x10a2f2ac0'\Uc131\Ub2a5\Uc810\Uac80\Uae30\Ub85d\Ubd80']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1706817c0 'UISV-spacing' V:[Common.DetailProgressView:0x10a2f2ac0'\Uc131\Ub2a5\Uc810\Uac80\Uae30\Ub85d\Ubd80']-(8)-[Common.DetailProgressView:0x10a2d9840'\Uc774\Uc804\Ub4f1\Ub85d\Uc99d']   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17068d890 V:[Common.RippleView:0x10a2d3600]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':Common.DetailProgressView:0x10a2f2ac0'성능점검기록부' )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2017-10-11 15:31:54.657816 dealer[306:22643] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170681ae0 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x10b745ee0.top == Common.DetailProgressView:0x10b7460a0'\Uac80\Ucc28\Uacb0\Uacfc'.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170681b80 'UISV-canvas-connection' V:[Common.DetailProgressView:0x10a2d9840'\Uc774\Uc804\Ub4f1\Ub85d\Uc99d']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x10b745ee0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170681ea0 'UISV-hiding' UIStackView:0x10b745ee0.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170681c20 'UISV-spacing' V:[Common.DetailProgressView:0x10b7460a0'\Uac80\Ucc28\Uacb0\Uacfc']-(8)-[Common.DetailProgressView:0x10a2f2ac0'\Uc131\Ub2a5\Uc810\Uac80\Uae30\Ub85d\Ubd80']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1706817c0 'UISV-spacing' V:[Common.DetailProgressView:0x10a2f2ac0'\Uc131\Ub2a5\Uc810\Uac80\Uae30\Ub85d\Ubd80']-(8)-[Common.DetailProgressView:0x10a2d9840'\Uc774\Uc804\Ub4f1\Ub85d\Uc99d']   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1706817c0 'UISV-spacing' V:[Common.DetailProgressView:0x10a2f2ac0'성능점검기록부']-(8)-[Common.DetailProgressView:0x10a2d9840'이전등록증']   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2017-10-11 15:31:54.658671 dealer[306:22643] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17069b8a0 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x10a0cdf70.top == Common.HDLabel:0x102dc5340'\Uacac\Uc801\Uc774 \Ub192\Uc740 \Uc21c\Uc73c\Ub85c \Uc815\Ub82c\Ub429\Ub2c8\Ub2e4.'.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17069b9e0 'UISV-canvas-connection' V:[Common.ReceivedEstimateView:0x10a0a8220]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x10a0cdf70 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174499f50 'UISV-hiding' UIStackView:0x10a0cdf70.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17069bc60 'UISV-spacing' V:[Common.HDLabel:0x102dc5340'\Uacac\Uc801\Uc774 \Ub192\Uc740 \Uc21c\Uc73c\Ub85c \Uc815\Ub82c\Ub429\Ub2c8\Ub2e4.']-(8)-[Common.ReceivedEstimateView:0x10a0a8220]   (active)>"
)
```

I suspect that these are related to the spacing of hidden UIStackView.

Because all of troubled views are in the hidden UIStackView. And the only thing that exists between them is the spacing of UIStackView.

But I can't adjust the spacing of UIStackView using AutoLayout. (Maybe everyone is too. Aren't?)

So I don't know how to solve this problem. I want to know the cause and solution of this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: [wtfautolayout.com](http://wtfautolayout.com) is a very useful tool for solving these sorts of issues.  In this case there is a conflict between the constraints stack view uses for hiding the components and your other vertical constraints; simply set your constraints priorities to 999 so that the stackview can override them when necessary and it should be OK.

Comment: @Paulw11 lol what the cool named website. thanks